# How to speed up sum of an array elements?

Tags: python, numba, f2py

I would like to do the sum of a 3d array but grouping the elements n by n. Doing it explicitly it requires a lot of execution time.

I have tried with numba and it is not improving. With f2py it might work but I would prefer to skip it in this case.

```
fsum=np.zeros([N,M,L])
for i in range(0,N):
     for j in range(1,M-1):
       for k in range(0,L):
           for h in range(j-5,j+5):
               fsum[i,j,k]=fsum[i,j,k]+g[i,h,k]
```

I would like to find a way to write it in such a way to improve performances. How can I do it?

Comment: What is the ndarray `g`?

Comment: It is just a numpy array. All these objects contain numbers. if fsum has 100 elements (0<k<100) g has 1000 elements (0<h<1000)

Comment: There was a mistake in the loops...not it should be fine!
`fsum=np.zeros([N,M,L])
    for i in range(0,N):
     for j in range(1,M-1):
       for k in range(0,L):
           for h in range(j-5,j+5):
               fsum[i,j,k]=fsum[i,j,k]+g[i,h,k]`

Comment: Please show your numba decorator of the function. Specify input/output dtypes like `@njit('i8[:](f8[:], f8[:])', cache=True)` leads to speed up.

Comment: I am looking for something speeding up. I tried something simple for numba decorator suche as `@njit(parallel=True,fastmath=True)`..

Comment: Types specification should help http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/types.html

Comment: Caution! This is **NOT TRUE**! Type specification **will not help** with performance, once the function is cached! In fact, type specifications currently seem to slightly slow down numba (as of version 0.42).

Comment: So then which would be the best numba implementation?

Comment: Either just explicitly loop over it with `parallel=True` or use implemented numpy functions. `fastmath=True` might also help.

Comment: Which is what I have tried without any effect!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use scipy then there is a n-d convolution available:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import convolve
```

### This is your imput

```
g = np.ones((100,100,5)
```

### Here you define the "window" of the convolution

```
ker = np.ones((1,11,1)) # = [[[1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1]]]
```

### Then you compute the convolution with a mode to handle border

```
# constant means that a 0-padding will be added to border to compute the convolution
fmat = convolve(g, ker, mode='constant')
```

### Display the result

```
print(fmat)
```

Cf. [Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html) for more details.

EDIT:

You want to sum elements five by five for the second dimension. So you want to compute for each pixel, the sum of a 1x11x1 window around this pixel (that's your for loop with a range from j-5 to j+5). This can be computed using a convolution (ex. applying a filter to an image is a convolution).

Comment: thanks a lot but I don't get gmat and the logic behind this. Could you explain it?

Comment: Yes, it did but I tried and I failed. I went, so far, for f2py which is faster!